# PHP oop Mysql fetching variable property

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i can manage to fetch a field from my database, which returns an object with a couple of properties such id, height, width, top, ... and one of these properties is called props which contains an array of the names of the properties that I need, for example it could be : ('top','bottom','left','right'). now what I'm trying to do is to iterate through $props values and fetch the property from the original object, and add it to a string. so let's say the fetched class from database is called $element, I have :

```
    $props=$element->props;
    foreach($props as $property){
        $style .= $property." : ".$element->{$property}."; ";
    }
    unset($property);
```

but what I end up in $style is something like  `top : ; left : ; bottom : ; right : ;` and obviously the `$element->{$property}` part of the code is not returning anything. I've tried lots of alternatives but I can't figure out what's going on, can anyone help me ?

Comment: Are you sure there is a `$element->top`, or `$element->left`, or `$element->bottom` or `$element->right` ?

Comment: Would you mind copying the results from die(print_r($element)); ?

Comment: @CoryJThompson
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 1
    [type] => image
    [top] => 266
    [left] => 285
    [width] => 195
    [height] => 184
    [props] => Array
        (
            [0] => position
            [1] =>  border-width
            [2] =>  width
            [3] =>  height
            [4] =>  top
            [5] =>  left
            [6] =>  border-color
            [7] =>  margin
        )

)

Comment: @qwertymk yes, I've checked them individually and they work

Comment: @hakim-sina works for me **[here](http://ideone.com/1KkTsy)**

Comment: @qwertymk I rewrote the original object and this it works for me too ! I think there was a white space issue before

Answer (score 0):

If indeed your object has a property such as `top`, I would try this approach as the curly braces are not needed if you're trying to reach the element object's top|left|bottom|right properties:

```
$props=$element->props;
foreach($props as $property){
    $style .= $property . " : " . $element->$property . "; ";
}
```

If I may suggest a small tweak to make it more apparent what you're doing here, string concatenation can get pretty ugly, especially if you're using semicolons which are meaningful in PHP:

```
$props = $element->props;
foreach($props as $property){
    $style_format = '%s : %s; ";
    $style .= sprintf($style_format, $property, $element->$property);
}
```

Comment: I've tried it without the curly braces, I've even tried 
echo $element->$property;
which doesnt return anything :(

Comment: Then I suggest that $element->top, etc., do not exist; at least not as you're expecting it.

Comment: yup, I think that was the problem, there were extra space at the beginning of each property for some reason ! thanks for the help anyway